# Jira REST API with proxy (Java)

Tags: java, proxy, jira

I would like to use the Jira REST Client API for Java in an application that needs to go through a proxy to access the desired Jira instance. Unfortunately I didn't find a way to set it when using the given factory from that library:

```java
JiraRestClientFactory factory = new AsynchronousJiraRestClientFactory();
String authentication = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString("username:password".toBytes());
return factory.createWithAuthenticationHandler(URI.create(JIRA_URL), new BasicAuthenticationHandler(authentication));
```

How can we use the Jira API and set a proxy ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only solution I found on the internet was to set it with system parameters (see solution 1 below). Unfortunately that did not fit my requirements as in the company I work for, there are multiple proxies and depending on the service to call, it has to use another proxy configuration. In that case, I cannot set the system properties without destroying all calls to other services that would need another proxy.

Nevertheless, I was able to find a way to set it by re-implementing some classes (see solution 2).

**Important limitation:** the proxy server must not ask for credentials.

0. Context

Maybe as context before, I created a class containing proxy configuration:

```java
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
public class ProxyConfiguration {

    public static final Pattern PROXY_PATTERN = Pattern.compile("(https?):\\/\\/(.*):(\\d+)");

    private String scheme;
    private String host;
    private Integer port;

    public static ProxyConfiguration fromPath(String path) {
        Matcher matcher = PROXY_PATTERN.matcher(path);
        if (matcher.find()) {
            return new ProxyConfiguration(matcher.group(1), matcher.group(2), toInt(matcher.group(3)));
        }
        return null;
    }

    public String getPath() {
        return scheme + "://" + host + ":" + port;
    }

}
```

1. Set system properties for proxy

Call the following method with your proxy configuration at the start of the application or before using the Jira REST API:

```java
public static void configureProxy(ProxyConfiguration proxy) {
    if (proxy != null) {
        System.getProperties().setProperty("http.proxyHost", proxy.getHost());
        System.getProperties().setProperty("http.proxyPort", proxy.getPort().toString());
        System.getProperties().setProperty("https.proxyHost", proxy.getHost());
        System.getProperties().setProperty("https.proxyPort", proxy.getPort().toString());
    }
}
```

2. Re-implement `AsynchronousHttpClientFactory`

Unfortunately, as this class has many private inner classes and methods, you will have to do an ugly copy paste and change the following code to give the wanted proxy configuration:

```java
public DisposableHttpClient createClient(URI serverUri, ProxyConfiguration proxy, AuthenticationHandler authenticationHandler) {
    HttpClientOptions options = new HttpClientOptions();

    if (proxy != null) {
        options.setProxyOptions(new ProxyOptions.ProxyOptionsBuilder()
            .withProxy(HTTP, new Host(proxy.getHost(), proxy.getPort()))
            .withProxy(HTTPS, new Host(proxy.getHost(), proxy.getPort()))
            .build());
    }

    DefaultHttpClientFactory<?> defaultHttpClientFactory = ...
}
```

You can then use it (in the following example, my re-implementation of `AsynchronousHttpClientFactory` is called `AtlassianHttpClientFactory`):

```java
URI url = URI.create(JIRA_URL);
String authentication = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString("username:password".toBytes());
DisposableHttpClient client = new AtlassianHttpClientFactory().createClient(url, proxy, new BasicAuthenticationHandler(authentication));
return new AsynchronousJiraRestClient(url, client);
```

Note that after all those problems, I also decided to write a [Jira client library](https://github.com/Chavaillaz/jira-client) supporting authentication, proxy, multiple HTTP clients and working asynchronously with `CompletableFuture`.